# Convert past date to next day of week in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to make stream events repeat weekly. I've written the code below which works but seems obtuse. Is there a better way to go about this?
[A diagram of what I'd like to happen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAmfR.png)

If the event date is in the past, update the event date to the nearest future day of the week that the event was originally on.

(I added the check to see if it was currently the same day as the original stream day because PHP's Stringtotime "This Tuesday" would jump to Tuesday of next week if today was Tuesday. Is there a better way around this?)

I'm relatively new to php so any help would be great!

```
// If a stream is set to weekly, and it's already over, this code updates its start and end times to the next day week day that it originally aired on.
        if( ($weekly = true) && ($stream_end_epoch < $now) ){ //If Stream end date has past & repeat is turned on.
            $stream_day_epoch = strtotime(get_post_meta( $stream_id, 'stream_day', true ));
            $dayOfWeek = date("l", $stream_day_epoch);
            $currentDate = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone($time_zone) );
            $currentDay = $currentDate->format('l');
            
            //Update the stream dates to the soonest week day they aired on.
            if($dayOfWeek == $currentDay){
                $stream_start_epoch = strtotime('Today '. $stream_start . $time_zone ); // update start (Set to yesterday because I'm getting a weird 1 day offset that I dont know where its coming from. this is super hackey and will probably break at certain times in the day, but i'm leaving it in this code until I can figure out a real solution.)
                $stream_end_epoch = strtotime('Today '. $stream_end . $time_zone ); // update end.
            }else{
                $stream_start_epoch = strtotime('this '.$dayOfWeek. $stream_start . $time_zone ); // update start
                $stream_end_epoch = strtotime('this '.$dayOfWeek. $stream_end . $time_zone ); // update end.
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you please provide the values for `$stream_start`, `$stream_end` and `$time_zone`?

Answer (score 0):

I think this could work for you:

```
$event_date = strtotime('2021-06-9');
$today      = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));

if($event_date < $today):
    $dayOfWeek = date("l", $event_date);
    $todayDay  = date("l", $today);

    $event_date = ($dayOfWeek !== $todayDay) ? strtotime("next " . $dayOfWeek) : $today;
endif;

var_dump(date('Y-m-d', $event_date));
```

if you  set the event_date (for example) to 2021-06-04 (last Friday) the comparison will find that today is also Friday, so today is your next event day (and not on Friday of next week).

Comment: Okay thanks, seems like the logic is pretty similar but your code is obviously a lot shorter, and maybe more efficient? I actually prefer my code to lean toward ease of readability than brevity, but I think I can definitely clean mine up a bit haha. Thanks for the help!